# How to use cv::Mat::at<double>(i,j,k) (to access a multi channel matrix)?

Tags: c++, opencv

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main()
{
    double m[1][4][3] =
        {
            {{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}, {4.0, 5.0, 6.0}, {7.0, 8.0, 9.0}, {10.0, 11.0, 12.0}}};

    cv::Mat M(1, 4, CV_64FC3, m);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
                std::cout << M.at<double>(i, j, k) << std::endl;

    

    cv::namedWindow("Input", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cv::imshow("Input", M);
    cv::waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

#### Expected Output

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
6.0
7.0
8.0
9.0
10.0
11.0
12.0
```

#### Current Output

```
1
8.10465e-320
5.31665e-315
4
8.11058e-320
2.122e-314  
7
8.11355e-320
-9.44163e+21
10
7.16685e-308
0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

opencv treats the **number of channels** in each element of a [**`cv::Mat`**](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) as separate from the **number of dimensions**.

In your case `cv::Mat M(1, 4, CV_64FC3, m)` is a **2 dimensional** array where each element has **3 channels**.

[**`cv::Mat::at`**](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) returns an element in the `cv::Mat`.
In order to use it in your case you need to:

1. Pass 2 indices for the 2 dimensions.
2. Get a [**`cv::Vec3d`**](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ac40425b84f60b39fd35e03814122661f) value which holds an element with 3 channels of `double`s .
3. Iterate over the channels using [`operator[]`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d84/group__core__basic.html#ga370d94209693b5b13437ab4991cabf73) of `cv::Vec3d`.

**Complete example:**

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double m[1][4][3] = {{{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}, {4.0, 5.0, 6.0}, {7.0, 8.0, 9.0}, {10.0, 11.0, 12.0}} };
    cv::Mat M(1, 4, CV_64FC3, m);

    for (int i = 0; i < M.rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M.cols; ++j)
        {
            cv::Vec3d const& elem = M.at<cv::Vec3d>(i, j);
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
            {
                std::cout << elem[k] << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

---

**Note:**

Using `cv::Mat::at` for traversing a big matrix is not the most efficient way (and in debug builds it also incurs expensive validity checks).
A more efficient way it to use [**`cv::Mat::ptr`**](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a5a9ffc908ac90604f36a8b6a1038747d), which gives you direct access to row data.

Usage in your case (yields the same output):

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double m[1][4][3] = { {{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}, {4.0, 5.0, 6.0}, {7.0, 8.0, 9.0}, {10.0, 11.0, 12.0}} };
    cv::Mat M(1, 4, CV_64FC3, m);

    for (int i = 0; i < M.rows; ++i)
    {
    //----------------------------vvv---------------
        cv::Vec3d const* pRow = M.ptr<cv::Vec3d>(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < M.cols; ++j)
        {
            cv::Vec3d const& elem = pRow[j];
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
            {
                std::cout << elem[k] << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that validity checks of .at are only performed in debug build. Release mode build is very fast, afair faster than iterator but still slower than line-pointer access.

Comment: @Micka thanks for the correction. I rephrased.

Comment: To make it much stricter, I will do `cv::Vec3d const* const pRow = M.ptr<cv::Vec3d>(i);` . :-)